# How to compute the display width of a prompt on the CLI with ANSI escape codes?

Tags: terminal, rust, posix, readline

A trivial implementation:

```
extern crate unicode_width;

fn main () {
    let prompt = "\x1b[1;32m>>\x1b[0m ";
    println!("{}", unicode_width::UnicodeWidthStr::width(prompt));
}
```

returns `12` but `3` is expected.

I would also be happy to use a crate that already does this, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to get the width of an escape-sequence using a Unicode width calculation, simply because none of the string is printable—on a terminal.

If you control the content of the string, you could calculate the width by

- copying the string to a temporary variable
- substituting the escape sequences to empty strings, e.g., changing the pattern starting with `\x1b`, allowing any combination of `[`, `]`, `<`, `>`', `=`, `?`, `;` or decimal digits *through* the "final" characters in the range `@` to `~`
- measuring the length of what (if anything) is left.

In your example

```
let prompt = "\x1b[1;32m>>\x1b[0m ";
```

only `">> "` would be left to measure.

For patterns... you would start here: [Regex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/enum.Regex.html)

Further reading:

- [crate Regex](http://docs.nickel.rs/regex/index.html)
- [17.3 Strings](http://rustbyexample.com/std/str.html), Rust by Example

Comment: Can't some ANSI escapes move the cursor forwards or backwards, changing the overall width? Seems like transforming to an empty string wouldn't be complete if so.

Comment: You normally would not use those in your prompt, and you would not find their length by a character-type function.  OP's example does not go there, at any rate.  For instance, an escape sequence could save the cursor position, clear the screen and restore the cursor position.  Not topical for a prompt...